# Script#. How to add methods or members to BCL (to its script sharp's implementation)

Tags: script#

I want to extend some classes (Int64 with adding the Parse() method, ArrayList with ToArray method, or some else). Does anybody know the way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this doesn't address your real question (which stems from lack of extension methods... for now), but for the specific examples, the suggestion I have is to check out the project and its associated github repository if you haven't already done so (https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp), and making your updates in a fork so you aren't blocked, and subsequently also consider submitting a pull request so the changes can be incorporated back into the project if they generally make sense for other script# users.

Hope that helps.

Comment: any chance of opensourcing everything?